# How do I see the error that is causing an ECS deployment to fail?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I'm following a tutorial to create an ECS cluster, and the ECSService is stuck in CREATE_IN_PROGRESS under CloudFormation > Stacks > {stack name}

[image]

It looks like something is failing under Amazon Elastic Container Service > Clusters > {my cluster} > Services > {my service} > Deployments

[image]

I'm new to ECS, so I'm not sure where to see the details of what failed.  One suggestion was to log into the EC2 instance that was created as part of this stack and run some `docker` commands to see what's failing, but I don't know how to connect to these EC2 instances since they were created by this stack so I didn't have an option to load a key file for SSH, and Instance Connect doesn't work.

Here is my CloudFormation template.  How do I go about seeing what failed?

```
{
    "taskDefinitionArn": "arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:1234567890:task-definition/nginxdemos-hello:2",
    "containerDefinitions": [
        {
            "name": "nginxdemos-hello",
            "image": "nginxdemos/hello",
            "cpu": 0,
            "portMappings": [
                {
                    "name": "nginxdemos-hello-80-tcp",
                    "containerPort": 80,
                    "hostPort": 80,
                    "protocol": "tcp",
                    "appProtocol": "http"
                }
            ],
            "essential": true,
            "environment": [],
            "environmentFiles": [],
            "mountPoints": [],
            "volumesFrom": [],
            "logConfiguration": {
                "logDriver": "awslogs",
                "options": {
                    "awslogs-create-group": "true",
                    "awslogs-group": "/ecs/nginxdemos-hello",
                    "awslogs-region": "us-east-1",
                    "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "family": "nginxdemos-hello",
    "executionRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::1234567890:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole",
    "networkMode": "awsvpc",
    "revision": 2,
    "volumes": [],
    "status": "ACTIVE",
    "requiresAttributes": [
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.logging-driver.awslogs"
        },
        {
            "name": "ecs.capability.execution-role-awslogs"
        },
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.19"
        },
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.18"
        },
        {
            "name": "ecs.capability.task-eni"
        },
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.29"
        }
    ],
    "placementConstraints": [],
    "compatibilities": [
        "EC2",
        "FARGATE"
    ],
    "requiresCompatibilities": [
        "FARGATE"
    ],
    "cpu": "512",
    "memory": "1024",
    "runtimePlatform": {
        "cpuArchitecture": "X86_64",
        "operatingSystemFamily": "LINUX"
    },
    "registeredAt": "2023-03-03T23:11:41.450Z",
    "registeredBy": "arn:aws:iam::1234567890:user/Ben",
    "tags": []
```

Comment: Go to events of Ecs tasks, not service.

Comment: You've defined a log group named `/ecs/nginxdemos-hello`. Go to that log group in CloudWatch Logs to see the logs for the container.

Comment: @Marcin I went to Clusters > {my cluster} > Tasks > {task ID} > Logs, but there is nothing there.

Comment: A post on the forum for this tutorial said that the problem was that I had my CPU/Memory requirements too high in the task size.  I reduced the requirements and it's working now.  How could I have found that was the problem?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. @BenRubin, you originally had it at "cpu": "512", "memory": "1024". What did you set to to make it work? I tried 512/1024 & 1024/3072; both failed. How much do both need to be ??

Comment: @mbsf I don't remember what the numbers on the CloudFormation template were that worked, but I used 0.25 CPU and 0.5 GB memory through the UI.

Comment: @BenRubin, "cpu": "256", "memory": "512" as you suggested did work. Much appreciated! I'm now struggling how to troubleshoot this failure. I set it back to 512/1024 for troubleshooting. cloudformation doesn't tell you the size is big; just that it timed out. Bad omen for starting to learn & use AWS !